# ¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos

Tags: soporte, faq, comentarios, magic-links

En los comentarios, ¿cómo puedo evitar tener que poner `[meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/)` para poner un enlace el sitio Meta? ¿Se pueden usar magic-links en este sitio?

¿Qué son los magic-links? ¿Cómo funcionan? ¿Cuáles hay?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Esta es una traducción de la publicación original en inglés que [se tradujo](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2497/1674) para [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/).

---

En [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/209901) se detallan los magic-links que pueden utilizarse en los comentarios para los enlaces más comunes.

Paso a detallar los disponibles actualmente:

- `[meta]` – enlace a Meta; el texto del enlace es el nombre del sitio. No hace nada si ya se está en Meta.
- `[main]` – igual que [meta], pero al revés.
- `[edit]` – enlace a la página para editar la publicación donde está este comentario. El texto del enlace es "editar", respetando la capitalización dada.
- `[help]` se explica solo. Este y los siguientes subapartados tienen siempre el texto "centro de ayuda":
- `[meta-help]` enlaza a "¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?" (/help/whats-meta)
- `[help/on-topic]` enlaza a "¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?" (/help/on-topic)
- `[help/dont-ask]` enlaza a "¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?" (/help/dont-ask)
- `[help/behavior]` enlaza a "¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?" (/help/behavior).
- `[tour]` y `[meta-tour]` – equivalentes a la versión FAQ, pero enlaza al Tour de la página (resp. el Tour de la página Meta). El texto del enlace es "recorrido" (respetando las mayúsculas y minúsculas). También son válidas `[about]` y `[meta-about]`.
- `[ask]`, `[answer]` – enlaza a "Cómo preguntar" / "Cómo responder".
- `[so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`/`[meta.se]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – enlace a las páginas ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), el [Stack Exchange portal](http://stackexchange.com/)). El texto del enlace es el nombre del sitio.
- Los Stack Overflow internacionales pueden enlazarse con `[es.so]`, `[pt.so]`, `[ja.so]` y `[ru.so]`.
- `[loquesea.se]` – enlaza a loquesea.stackexchange.com, si dicho sitio existe. El texto del enlace es el nombre del sitio. Usa `[ubuntu.se]` para Ask Ubuntu. `[meta.loquesea.se]` enlaza al sitio meta correspondiente.
- `[chat]` – enlaza al chat del sitio actual http://chat.stackexchange.com/, donde se muestra una lista de las salas activas del sitio. El texto del enlace es "Chat de Stack Overflow en español".
- `[mcve]`, `[reprex]`, `[repro]`, `[mre]`, `[example]` – en el sitio principal (no en Meta) enlazan a la página [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) con el texto "Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable".
- `[tag:nombre-de-etiqueta]` como por ejemplo `[tag:java]` crea un enlace a dicha etiqueta, como [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). También funciona en los comentarios.
- `[meta-tag:nombre-de-etiqueta]` como por ejemplo `[meta-tag:discusión]` crea un enlace a dicha etiqueta en Meta, como [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n). También funciona en los comentarios.

Aparte de `[chat]`, [mcve] y `[edit]`, y además de `[chat-faq]`, todo funciona en el chat.

---

De esta forma, si vemos que un nuevo usuario necesita ayuda con el formato y la forma de escribir una pregunta aquí, podemos decir:

> Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a `[edit]` para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: `[¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic)`. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Que se imprimirá así:

> Hola y bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/posts/XXX/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [recorrido](/tour) y leer [Cómo preguntar](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: oh no tenia ni idea! esto me ahorra muchos caracteres hahah

Comment: A ver, esto es una prueba de en [meta] de [main] para ver si funcionan los vínculos a [help], lo cual me parece muy interesante. Si tienes algún vínculo más, dale en [edit]

Comment: @jachguate parece que funcionan :) Nótese que el de `[meta]` solo funciona en el sitio principal. También es bueno saber que cualquier magic-link puede usarse junto con otro texto diciendo  `[hola](/help/behavior)` por ejemplo --> [hola](/help/behavior).

Comment: @fedorqui, Si, eso veo, no conocía la característica y si que me viene bien. De hecho, si se pudiera pedir, pediría unos cuantos más al centro de ayuda. [help/mcve]  y [help/how-to-ask] o simplemente [mcve] y [how-to-ask] son los primeros que me vienen a la mente.

Comment: @jachguate en [la publicación original en Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/209901) la gente va pidiendo... y algunos los acaban añadiendo. `[mcve]` está pero solo en [so].

Comment: @fedorqui buena colección, no conocía la gran mayoría.

Comment: genial esto, no tenia ni idea, deja probar, [tour], [es.so], [mcve], [help], [edit]

Comment: @Reinier son geniales, ¿verdad? `[mcve]` solo funciona en el sitio principal, no en Meta.

Comment: @fedorqui muchas gracias por la aclaracion, pensé que no funcionaba, esto me ahorra mucho en los caracteres en los comentarios, sobre todo a los nuevos usuarios, thanks

Comment: Esto esta bueno

Comment: Muy utiles. Asi puedes dar un buen comentario constructivo a editar/como preguntaer a alguien nuevo. Aunque tengo una duda: si yo pongo `[edit](/edit)`, que tengo que editar? el `[edit]` supongo, no?

Comment: @Euricky999 estaba mal el ejemplo. En el caso de `edit`, es directamente `[edit]` sin más. En general, todo enlace va dentro de paréntesis y el texto que lo enlaza entre corchetes. Ahora bien, `[hola qué tal](/edit)` no funciona porque el paréntesis no es magic link.