# Magic link [mcve] deja texto del vínculo en inglés

Tags: bug, estado-completado

El [magic link](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1058/21) [mcve] no está funcionando correctamente en el sitio

He intentado utilizarlo de esta manera:

[image: texto de comentario]

Y el comentario ha quedado así:

[image: comentario publicado]

Con el *anchor text* en inglés.

El vínculo, sin embargo, si se ha establecido correctamente a la sección de la ayuda en es.stackoverflow.com: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero para avisar de fallos de traducción (incluyendo textos no traducidos) en adelante publica por favor una respuesta aquí: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83/sugerencias-de-mejora-en-las-traducciones

Comment: De hecho, lo mencionó Mariano [ayer mismo](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1099/83). @Konamiman de todos modos, a mí me sigue renderizando con el texto en inglés. [Véase ejemplo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30693/bash-tomar-los-n%C3%BAmeros-uid-min-y-uid-max/30859#comment60354_30859).

Comment: @fedorqui He importado la traducción desde Transifex, pero no será visible hasta la próxima compilación. Tranquilo, compilamos bastante a menudo. :-)

Comment: @Konamiman ah vaaale :)

Comment: @Konamiman, gracias, no había caído en la cuenta que era un simple error de traducción, imaginé algo más exótico para generar el texto.. jajaja. Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima.