# Pruebas de formato (Sandbox)

Tags: discusión, resaltado-de-sintaxis, magic-links, formato

La idea es tener un [**sandbox**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/304899) donde poder probar libremente el formato, resaltado y magic links en respuestas y comentarios, evitando contaminar el sitio principal.

Pueden crear lo que quieran abajo:

- Editar esta pregunta.
- Publicar respuestas a esta pregunta.
- Añadir comentarios a esta pregunta o a cualquier respuesta.
- Probar si hay bugs en el editor.
- Revertir ediciones.

No se puede:

- Publicar contenido no deseado.
- Reportar a un moderador como prueba.

Comment: Dado que esto puede crecer bastante, te sugiero utilizar un usuario de juguete para esta pregunta, tal y como [hacen en Puzzles](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/13975). De lo contrario, si hay muchas publicaciones puedes tener ciertos problemas de sordera por recibir tantas notificaciones :P

Comment: @fedorqui es cierto, lo pensé, pero necesitaba probar algo y no tengo otro usuario para hacerlo. Luego veo qué solución darle o la elimino si me canso de las notificaciones. Gracias por el consejo.

Comment: Sería mucho más util tener un editor decente en el sitio, algo WYSIWYG, como Hotmail lo tiene desde hace +20 años.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>No hay Wi-Fi
en la punta
de la pirámide</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Comment: No entiendo por qué esto debería ser siquiera posible, con tan sólo ver el código fuente y el resultado me hace sentir sucio >_<

Comment: #estamuychido #laspiramides #muchokbd

Answer (score 6):

Hagamos un examen de la vista para aquellos que deseen descifrar la respuesta de [lois6b](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1717/16841):

---

## A T U E 5 J W Q P W S L

### Q W Ñ O I F J C Ñ M O I H I

#### F G P Ñ J J K Q P Z C B V Q L

N C N Q W P 9 2 P W R L Q Q G F I

<sup>Z A L P E R G E 9 J N A X C 1 W E 1 W E R 3</sup>

<sup><sup>Ñ O I U X A Ñ S K D F J A U F A S L F G A L S D L F C</sup></sup>

<sup><sub><sup>P S D M C N S W E U I W E R 8 N S J S D O S N S S I O S D J J K S D</sup></sub></sup>

<sup><sub><sup><sub>S Q Ñ I O W E U R P I W E Y R T E U H J S F H L J K S F H F B V Z X N M C B V Z X</sub></sup></sub></sup>

<sup><sub><sup><sub><sup>E R G U I E R U I G X V C B J K L X I W E T U D J H K L S F G X S L D F K 5 2 A S K D J H Z B V X C A Ñ K J F A L K J Z</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup>

Comment: #tumuybien #nomelasabia

Comment: [help] somebody help

Comment: [help/on-topic]

Comment: [help/dont-ask]

Comment: [help/behavior]

Comment: [help/us/help/them/better]

Comment: Esto es un [mcve]

Answer (score 5):

```cpp
// esto debería ser C++
int patata = 0u;
// structured binding:
auto [a, b] = devuelvo_tupla();
// literales:
auto binario = 0b0000101010101000100110101;
auto octal = 0234345234523;
auto hexadecimal = 0x00203042;
auto decimal_hexadecimal = 0xC.68p+2;

Mayusculas M;
minusculas m;
CamelCase CC;
lowerCamelCase lCC;
snake_case sc;
```

Como esto funcione me va a dar un infartito

En un lugar de la mancha...

AEI.

[Yo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1708/2742).

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>0</sup>
1</sup>
2</sup>
3</sup>
4</sup>
5</sup>
6</sup>
7</sup>
8</sup>
9</sup>
A</sup>
B</sup>
C</sup>
D</sup>
E</sup>
F</sup>
G</sup>
H</sup>
I</sup>
J</sup>
K</sup>
L</sup>
M</sup>
N</sup>
O</sup>
P</sup>
Q</sup>
R</sup>
S</sup>
T</sup>
U</sup>
V</sup>
W</sup>
X</sup>
Y</sup>
Z</sup>

<sup>0
<sup>1
<sup>2
<sup>3
<sup>4
<sup>5
<sup>6
<sup>7
<sup>8
<sup>9
<sup>A
<sup>B
<sup>C
<sup>D
<sup>E
<sup>F
<sup>G
<sup>H
<sup>I
<sup>J
<sup>K
<sup>L
<sup>M
<sup>N
<sup>O
<sup>P
<sup>Q
<sup>R
<sup>S
<sup>T
<sup>U
<sup>V
<sup>W
<sup>X
<sup>Y
<sup>Z</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>`0`</sup>
`1`</sup>
`2`</sup>
`3`</sup>
`4`</sup>
`5`</sup>
`6`</sup>
`7`</sup>
`8`</sup>
`9`</sup>
`A`</sup>
`B`</sup>
`C`</sup>
`D`</sup>
`E`</sup>
`F`</sup>
`G`</sup>
`H`</sup>
`I`</sup>
`J`</sup>
`K`</sup>
`L`</sup>
`M`</sup>
`N`</sup>
`O`</sup>
`P`</sup>
`Q`</sup>
`R`</sup>
`S`</sup>
`T`</sup>
`U`</sup>
`V`</sup>
`W`</sup>
`X`</sup>
`Y`</sup>
`Z`</sup>

<sup>`0`
<sup>`1`
<sup>`2`
<sup>`3`
<sup>`4`
<sup>`5`
<sup>`6`
<sup>`7`
<sup>`8`
<sup>`9`
<sup>`A`
<sup>`B`
<sup>`C`
<sup>`D`
<sup>`E`
<sup>`F`
<sup>`G`
<sup>`H`
<sup>`I`
<sup>`J`
<sup>`K`
<sup>`L`
<sup>`M`
<sup>`N`
<sup>`O`
<sup>`P`
<sup>`Q`
<sup>`R`
<sup>`S`
<sup>`T`
<sup>`U`
<sup>`V`
<sup>`W`
<sup>`X`
<sup>`Y`
<sup>`Z`</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

<sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup></sup><sup>0<sup>1<sup>2<sup>3<sup>4<sup>5<sup>6<sup>7<sup>8<sup>9<sup>A<sup>B<sup>C<sup>D<sup>E<sup>F<sup>G<sup>H<sup>I<sup>J<sup>K<sup>L<sup>M<sup>N<sup>O<sup>P<sup>Q<sup>R<sup>S<sup>T<sup>U<sup>V<sup>W<sup>X<sup>Y<sup>Z</sup>Y</sup>X</sup>W</sup>V</sup>U</sup>T</sup>S</sup>R</sup>Q</sup>P</sup>O</sup>N</sup>M</sup>L</sup>K</sup>J</sup>I</sup>H</sup>G</sup>F</sup>E</sup>D</sup>C</sup>B</sup>A</sup>9</sup>8</sup>7</sup>6</sup>5</sup>4</sup>3</sup>2</sup>1</sup>0</sup>

Comment: Guarden el desfibrilador! Sólo se permiten unas pocas etiquetas y no hay XSS! [Sigue vivo](https://media.tenor.co/images/b2df0235b903a8bca29e4fcfc828d149/tenor.gif)!

Comment: Dije un infartito, no un infartazo.

Comment: Imágenes en comentarios <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/ae/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg/23px-Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg.png"/>

Answer (score 5):

<sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>heheh a ver quien lee esto sin el modo edición (el movil no cuenta, Mariano ¬¬ )</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup>

Comment: ¡[Yo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aigj.png)! :D

Comment: y [sin zoom](https://i.imgur.com/zLoXwdA.png)

Comment: Aquí tienes [otro hack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL28X.png) :P

Comment: @Flxtr si! ese es el que más nos representa ^^

Comment: Copy-paste, 2 segundos :P

Comment: @lois6b seleccione el texto y click derecho "buscar tu texto" en Google ;)

Comment: @lois6b Nuevo record --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJGvX.png

Comment: @Mariano ni vi el reporte! me fijo mucho en la pagina de publicaciones activas y vi una respuesta de un user con 1 de rep y eso siempre me hace mirar qué contestó. Este usuario hizo la misma respuesta ayer en otro sitio. es spam

Comment: @mariano ya que no soy Madrugator (me quitaron el puesto unos cuantos users) sigo siendo el más rapido del oeste xDD

Comment: ~prueba~s sdf dfdfadf ---adfasdfa---

Answer (score 4):

Doble apóstrofe para dibujar dentro un apóstrofe

Dado: `` (_causa) => axios.post(`${BASEURL}/causas`, _causa) `` solo se puede con doble apóstrofe.

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

``` ``(_causa) => axios.post(`${BASEURL}/causas`, _causa)`` ```

#posnosabia #nosirvenloshashtag #niquefuerainstagram #nosgraduamosenmayo

Comment: #nosgraduamosenmayo está comenzando a ser tendencia en tu zona

Comment: Hola . Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, si bien es totalmente válida, _debería_ dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayúdanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto; No explica qué se está haciendo ni de dónde salió ese fragmento, ni por qué estás interesado en entenderlo, ni nada que nos de alguna pista del objetivo. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: Hola , bienvenido a [es.so]. Lamento decirte que tu pregunta no cumple con el estándar mínimo de calidad que se requiere en la comunidad. Por favor edita tu pregunta añadiendo la información que nos permita comprender tu problema. Sigue esta guía: __[mcve]__.

Comment: Hola . Lastimosamente, este tipo de preguntas tan abiertas no se pueden realizar en el sitio. Sin embargo, puedes acceder al salón de chat donde esas preguntas son bienvenidas puesto que el chat es más informal y las personas cuentan sus opiniones sobre diversos temas. Solo haz click en el enlace de este comentario.

Comment: Hola . Lastimosamente, este tipo de preguntas tan abiertas no se pueden realizar en el sitio. Sin embargo, puedes acceder al [salón de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde esas preguntas son bienvenidas puesto que el chat es más informal y las personas cuentan sus opiniones sobre diversos temas. Solo haz click en el enlace de este comentario.

Comment: wtf tus hashtag y comentarios xDDDD

Answer (score 2):

> Ahora me ves

...

> Ahora no me ves

```
`Yo`, soy tu padre
```

```
   throw new exception # en esta línea tengo problemas :(
```

`` `Carambolas` ``

The *Gamma function* satisfying $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!\quad\forall
n\in\mathbb N$ is via through the Euler integral

$$
\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\,.
$$

No funciona MathJax :( T_T

Comment: no llores.... xD

Comment: Es que quería hacer una guiki :c

Answer (score 1):

**saludos**

Sí me borra:

```
Hola 6789012345678901
Saludos 9012345678901
Buenos días
Estimados
Que tal estáis
Queridos foreros
Hola 6789012345678901,34567890
Gracias a std::regex, pude lograr esto
```

No me borra:

```
Hola 67890123456789012
Hola123
Buen día
Estimadas
Qué tal estáis
Querido foro
Gracias a std::regex pude lograr esto
**saludos**
```

(Pruebas al hilo de [Los saludos en castellano ya se eliminan automáticamente de los encabezados de las publicaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3149/83))

Comment: Ahh... caracteres **en la primera línea**.. me faltó ese detalle

Comment: @Mariano claro, y hasta un signo de puntuación :)

Comment: Claro que no toma acentos... SO no tiene una filosofía de aceptarlos (o entender que las letras son más que a-z) hasta que alguien le marca el error :-/

Comment: @Mariano los signos de puntuación que se tienen en cuenta [son `[.,;!-]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/209901).

Comment: Y ese último es uno de los casos por los cuales no soy tan fanático de las eliminaciones automáticas (un caso demasiado límite, pero se elimina información importante para una pregunta).

Comment: Sí, vi los símbolos, pero ese regex no es lo que en realidad implementaron, así que me sumé a tus pruebas... Y menos mal que no implementaron ese regex, porque realmente da pena!! Ver algo como `(i|e)` en vez de `[ie]`, o `\s*` al final, me arde en los ojos :-P

Answer (score 1):

## React con JSX :)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { counter } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {`Has dado click ${counter} ${counter === 1 ? 'vez' : 'veces'}`}
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({counter: counter+1})}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

## React con JSX y ¡Hooks!

```js
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      {`Has dado click ${counter} ${counter === 1 ? 'vez' : 'veces'}`}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter+1)}>Click</button>
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba:

| Inline Code | Code Block |
| --- | --- |
| `a = 1` | `a = 1` `b = 2` |

Answer (score 0):

> ## <kbd>[magic-button-with-magic-tag-with-magic-button](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-button-with-magic-tag-with-magic-button)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

> Prueba de pasar el código de [¿ Cómo creo un componente en webix que sea un agregado de varios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66520/65) a stack snippet

El siguiente código, corresponde al primer bloque de código en la pregunta referida. Devolvía el error indicado abajo porque las referencias a librerías externas incluían `http` en lugar de `https`

```
Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: webix is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 18,
  "colno": 1
}
```

```js
webix.ready( function( ) {
  var w = 50,
      h = 50,
      s = 10;

  webix.ui( {
      rows: [
        { cols: [
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          ]
        },
        { height: s },
        { cols: [
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          ]
        },
        { height: s },
        { cols: [
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          ]
        }
      ]
    } )
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix_debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: He seguido las indicaciones de tu pregunta [¿ Cómo debuggear los errores que devuelve stacksnippet ?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1825/19610). El problema era la URL al `cdn`, que era `http://` y Chrome se negaba a cargarla. Al cambiarla a `https://`, el *snippet* funciona correctamente. Estoy editando la pregunta.

Comment: jaja, sabía que se me iba a olvidar. Que bueno que encontraste esa pregunta; muchas gracias por el comentario y la edición.

Answer (score 0):

Resaltado de sintaxis:

```
import this  # con language: python
print(23)
```

```python
import this  # con language: lang-python
print(23)
```

```py
import this  # con language: lang-py
print(23)
```

Comment: Varias veces me pregunté lo mismo... python a secas toma el lenguaje definido en la etiqueta [tag:Python], que es lang-python... La diferencia con lang-py no la sé (si es que hay alguna)

Comment: @Mariano ¿con _python a secas_ te refieres a `language: python`? En principio no, como comento en [esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3248/83).

Comment: Tenés razón, me equivoqué en cuál se usa. Pero `language: python` te aseguro que obtiene el resaltado definido en la etiqueta, es decir `lang-py`... Está explicado en MSE (por Jon Skeet si no me equivoco)

Comment: @Mariano pero entiendo que en los casos en los que la pregunta tenga la etiqueta [tag:python-x], ¿no? ¿O es para los casos raros en que hay código de distintos lenguajes?

Comment: no, en cualquier pregunta.. usar `language: python` toma la sintaxis definida en la etiqueta [tag:Python] (hoy es `lang-py`, pero va a tomar la que sea si se cambia en el futuro)... Eso vale para cualquier etiqueta... Dejame buscar (odio buscar desde el celu)

Comment: @Mariano aaaah no sabía. Me parece una forma algo rebuscada, pero no en vano útil. Entiendo que aquí en Meta no me funcionó porque [meta-tag:python] no existe. Actualizo la otra respuesta. Añado: sí, [funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/144068/revisions).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/304899 (al final, hinting tags). Y no sé cómo funciona en Meta (supongo que toma default por no encontrar la etiqueta, pero podría estar tomando las del sitio principal... Imposible saber sin ver cómo renderiza el HTML, imposible desde el celu)

Comment: @Mariano ya veo. Precisamente esa parte no la entendí y la dejé sin traducir cuando publiqué [Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/83)

Comment: es irrelevante... No se me ocurren casos de uso, salvo que pueden ser menos letras para escribir... Y agrego que desde la app estaba viendo resaltados a los 3... Abrí desde Chrome y ahí vi que no resalta, entonces sí, evidentemente no lo toma en Meta porque no está definido en una etiqueta de meta

Comment: [os] [tour] [recorrido](/tour)

Comment: @RodrigoN ¿será que quieres probar `[tag:os]`?

Comment: fedorqui, gracias. En realidad estaba buscando [es.so]. Aprovecho de preguntar como usar magic links para enlaces externos.

Comment: @RodrigoN puedes consultar [la info sobre magic links](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1058/83). Lo de enlaces externos no sé a qué te refieres, pero si se trata de enlazar webs [como ahora que enlazo google](http://www.google.com) se hace así: `[como ahora que enlazo google](http://www.google.com)`.

Comment: fedorqui, gracias nuevamente. Eso es justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 0):

No se de html como ustedes, pero con un simple programa de Python y un poco de paint...

```py
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("hola.png").convert("RGB")
pixels = image.load()

texto = ""

anterior_is_url = False

for y in range(image.height):
    for x in range(image.width):
        color = pixels[x, y]

        if(color == (255, 255, 255)):
            if(anterior_is_url):
                texto += "][false_url]"

            texto += "░░"
            anterior_is_url = False
            
        elif(color == (0,0,0)):
            if(anterior_is_url):
                texto += "][false_url]"

            texto += "██"
            anterior_is_url = False
        else:
            if(not anterior_is_url):
                texto += "["

            texto += "██"
            anterior_is_url = True

    texto += "  \n"

print(texto)
```

Generé una "imagen" con texto usando urls falsas para lograr el color rojo.

████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░██████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░
██[██████████████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)████░░░░░░██[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██
██[██████████████████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)████░░░░░░░░░░░░██[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██
██[██](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)████████████[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░██[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░
██[██](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░██[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░██[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░██[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░
██[██](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░
██[██](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░██[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░
██[██](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░
██[██](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░██[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)████[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░
██[██](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░██[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)████[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░
██[██](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)████████████[██████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░██[██████████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░
██[██████████████████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░
██[██████████████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░
██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░
██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░
██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░
██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░
██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░
██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░
██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██[████](http://okakpaskaspqwodqwpoqkdd.com)██░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░

Se que es algo simple, pero espero que lo aprecien c:

Ahora que lo pienso, en mi pantalla se ve bien, pero no se en otras. Y segurisimo de que no se ve bien en telefono.