# Es correcto agregar el código de algún lenguaje de programación usando la etiqueta <pre>

Tags: soporte, formato

Hola amigos en varias preguntas mias y otras que edito se debe usar el `<pre>` para agregar el código  de un lenguaje de programacion?, yo uso el editor para agregar codigo HTML, porque se acomoda mejor el codigo, esta correcto usarlo para agregar codigo de programacion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El editor de Stack Exchange acepta el uso de Markdown y de HTML. Los detalles se explican en [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones usando Markdown o HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) dónde se menciona que es posible usar `<pre>` entre de otras etiquetas HTML.

Nótese que que además de la etiqueta mencionada hay otras opciones para agregar código y cabe destacar que aquí contamos con [Pruebas de formato (Sandbox)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1706/65) para hacer pruebas de formato.