# ¿Podemos tener la dirección s.tk/esso o s.tk/soes para que dirija a Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, s.tk

Leyendo [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109802/209901) descubrí que Stack Exchange usa el dominio `s.tk` como acortador de direcciones.

Así, uno puede ir a [s.tk/](http://stackexchange.com/) y le dirigirá a StackExchange.com. Lo mismo con [s.tk/blog](http://s.tk/blog), que lleva al Blog de Stack Exchange. Etcétera.

Además, hay una serie de sitios de la red que están disponibles con este acortador: [s.tk/android](http://s.tk/android) para el sitio de Android, por ejemplo. Y, especialmente, [s.tk/ptso](http://s.tk/ptso) para Stack Overflow em Português.

¿Sería pues posible disponer de **s.tk/esso** o (incluso mejor) **s.tk/soes** para que dirigiera a http://es.stackoverflow.com y así ahorrarnos unos segundos vitales cada mañana?

Comment: No sabía de `s.tk` (: En relación a ahorrar "segundos vitales", no creo que ese sea un argumento de peso, sin embargo, creo que como alternativa a los QR o bien prevenir errores de tecleo es buena.

Comment: no conocia eso de s.tk, pero ahora si. yo uso el autocompletado* del navegador cada mañana y solo uso `es` y el me lo completa menos teclas que `s.tk`.Saludos P.D: *es una broma por si no se nota, ademas que s.tk tiene muchas mas utilidades, gracias por la info

Comment: @fedorqui: Lo tenía anotado en mi lista de posibles propuestas! ... No tanto por el uso que se le dé, sino para aparecer en el listado de MSE. -Cualquier publicidad es buena.

Comment: ¡votemos por el mejor!

Comment: @JuanM ¿y qué tal solo **http://s.tk/es**? Eso es más corto, y es el único que está en español. ¿Se puede agregar como respuesta?

Comment: dicho y hecho @ArtEze

Comment: Acabo de llegar a esta pregunta, porque en un comentario a un OP añadía varios enlaces de SOes y sobrepasaba el límite de caracteres, ahora con este acortador (poco conocido) evité tener que dejar dos o tres comentarios

Comment: @JheymanMejia ¡qué bien! Leéte igualmente [la información sobre los magic links](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1058/83) pues seguramente también te ayuden a acortar los comentarios. Por ejemplo, `[es.so]` se ve así: [es.so].

Comment: @fedorqui [yo después de conocer los magic links](https://memecrunch.com/meme/BGM9G/por-que-nadie-me-lo-dijo-ay-debo-haber-parecido-un-idiota/image.png?w=960&c=1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## **Actualización:**

Pueden ahora usar este URL corto para llegar al sitio: **http://s.tk/soes**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Pienso que el mejor URL corto seria:

### s.tk/soes

Comment: Esto es SOes desde el principio.

Comment: me quedo con SOes :D

Comment: Parece que ganó esta opción por goleada :) Cuando quieras la acepto y así cerramos la encuesta, Juan

Comment: @fedorqui my bien, ¡pediré esta entonces!

Comment: @JuanM ¡qué bien! Muchas gracias

Comment: @JuanM ¿en ese gif se muestra el gato hombre?

Comment: @Flxtr Sí, es un tributo al gato hombre.

Answer (score 4):

Pienso que el mejor URL corto seria:

### s.tk/es

Comment: Considerando que s.tk se refiere a stack exchange, la mejor opción por ser mas corta, y lógica dado que se usa el código de dos letras de idioma sin nada más y por ende más fácilmente "extendible" a otros idiomas es esta

Comment: @Rubén http://s.tk redirige a Stack Exchange en vez de StackOverflow, pero me parece que podría representar nuestro idioma.

Comment: @ArtEze: Gracias por la observación. Alcancé a corregir mi comentario (:

Answer (score -1):

Pienso que el mejor URL corto seria:

### s.tk/esso

Comment: Me recuerda a marca de gasolina(eras) -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esso

Comment: el tagline podría ser "dale gas"