# Uso de emojis o entidades HTML válidos para Stackoverflow

Tags: discusión

He visto en algunos nombres de usuarios y en comentarios de algunos que aparecen emojis o entidades HTML.

Yo he podido usarlos en preguntas/respuestas, pero no en comentarios.

Por ejemplo, en una respuesta yo uso esta entidad `&rtrif;` ▸ y funciona (▸[ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129545/29967)), sin embargó **intenté usarla en un comentario y no funcionó**, probé también con esta `&#x25ba` &#x25ba que es parecida, y tampoco funciona.

¿A qué se debe que no funcione en comentarios? ¿O en comentarios sólo se puede usar ciertas entidades? ¿Hay algún sitio que indique las entidades válidas para usar en Stackoverflow y en qué partes se pueden usar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la preguntas y respuestas se permite usar [Markdown y HTML para dar formato al texto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) y por eso se pueden usar entidades y etiquetas HTML.

> NOTA: Para más información, la lista de etiquetas válidas que se pueden usar en Stack Overflow se puede encontrar en esta [respuesta de Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/274671).

Pero los comentarios, como ya se ha mencionado en otras publicaciones, son diferentes y una especie de elementos de segunda en Stack Overflow: no se pueden editar después de 5 minutos, no se indexan, tienen una longitud limitada,... y no permiten código ni Markdown (o sólo una versión limitada como por ejemplo para añadir enlaces).

Por eso las entidades HTML no funcionan cuando se escribe un comentario. Pero sí que permiten Unicode, con lo cual habría una manera de *saltarse* esa limitación: en lugar de usar su código, copia y pega el carácter en un comentario (ver abajo en la sección de comentarios).

Comment: Si escribo &#x25ba; no se va a transformar en el símbolo, pero como se permite Unicode, puedo copiar y pegarlo directamente: ►.

Comment: *Los comentarios ...no permiten código Markdown*... Sin embargo en comentarios se puede usar esto para enlazar algo `[Texto visible](URL enlace )`, ¿eso no es Markdown?

Comment: @A.Cedano he editado esa parte para indicar que es una versión limitada de Markdown. Voy a buscar en meta para ver si se admite algo más que enlaces y lo pongo.

Comment: `[tag:nombre]` y [¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1058/127) o https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting ;-)