# Magic-link [mcve] no funciona en comentarios en Meta

Tags: característica-nueva, magic-links

Recién publiqué [un comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3299/advertencias-en-preguntas-potencialemente-problem%C3%A1ticas#comment11900_3314) en Meta incluyendo `[mcve]` pero no se convirtió en link.

El FAQ sobre magic-links menciona que funciona en el sitio principal pero no en Meta. Me parece que debería funcionar en ambos por lo cual solicito su incorporación.

Referencia

[¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1058/65)

Comment: Prueba de [mcve]

Comment: No estoy seguro que en Meta funcionen, pero en el sitio principal deberían ;)

Comment: De hecho [tú mismo fuiste quien notó que no funciona en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058/conoces-los-magic-links-para-los-comentarios-aprende-a-usarlos#comment4337_1059). Si va a ser una propuesta, sugiero poner un título más imperativo. Dicho lo cual, no veo la necesidad de que [mcve] funcione en Meta: es un recurso para enlazar a [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](/help/mcve), a la cual no veo ninguna utilidad en Meta pues las directrices que da son sobre preguntas de programación, algo que no está en el ámbito de trabajo de Meta.

Comment: Si habilitamos `[mcve]` en Meta, ¿no estaríamos dando la falsa impresión de que las preguntas de Meta deberían tener un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable? Al contrario, creo que es mejor que no se habilite (a menos que no esté entendiendo en qué caso sería interesante usarlo).