# Magic-links a la mano

Tags: característica-nueva, magic-links

Generalmente, cuando estoy revisando alguna pregunta y quiero echar mano de los magic-links me toca ir a buscar a meta el post donde están resumidos los magic-links ([¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058/conoces-los-magic-links-para-los-comentarios-aprende-a-usarlos)).

Si bien esto no implica mayor esfuerzo, creo que sería genial si en el panel de la derecha de SO estuviera un panel con acceso rápido a los Magic-links.

No se si lo vean viable, solo digo que sería genial.

Comment: Podria ser, pero como esto implica un cambio de diseño de toda la red, tendrias que proponerlo a nivel global en [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Uno acaba aprendiéndose los más comunes. Dicho lo cual, sí sería bueno que tuviera más visibilidad para que todos los conozcan.

Comment: Yo apenas estoy comenzando a navegar un poco más en SOes, y tengo entendido que hay una Wiki (No se dónde, por cierto). ¿Podrían ponerse en la wiki para darles más visibilidad como dice @fedorqui)?

Comment: @CamiloBernal Me pregunto si por "wiki" esperas un sitio especial y desconozcas que las preguntas y respuestas se pueden marcar como "wiki de comunidad". Aqui en Meta tenemos un etiqueta especial para preguntas sobre esto [meta-tag:wiki-de-comunidad], por otro lado también tenemos otra etiqueta para la preguntas frecuentas las cuales en su mayoría son "wikis" [meta-tag:faq]

Comment: si @Rubén más o menos en eso estaba pensando. Como dije en el otro comentario, apenas estoy explorando SOes y no sabía como se manejaba la "wiki".

Comment: @CamiloBernal Por si aún no lo encuentras, aquí el "wiki-indice" del faq: [FAQ de la Comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/65)