# Todos los "textos" de los magic links que apuntan al Centro de Ayuda tienen el mismo contenido

Tags: característica-nueva, magic-links

Últimamente he estado utilizando algunos [*magic links*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1058/83) y veo que algunos no funcionan tal como uno esperaría. Me explico: en algunos aparece el texto "Centro de Ayuda" cuando debería mostrar el título de la página a la que enlazan.

No los he probado todos, pero enumero algunos de los que he visto que muestran este comportamiento:

- `[help/on-topic]`
- `[help/dont-ask]`
- `[help/behavior]`

Cuando uno pone un comentario con estos *magic links*, su lectura no es "fácil", ejemplo:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, siempre resuelven con el mismo texto ***centro de ayuda***. ¿No sería más útil que resolvieran a un texto específico para cada caso?

Comment: déjame ver [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [help/behavior] si es cierto

Comment: Ese es el comportamiento esperado, si quieres que su comportamiento sea diferente tal vez convenga hacer una pregunta con la etiqueta [meta-tag:característica-nueva]

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058/conoces-los-magic-links-para-los-comentarios-aprende-a-usarlos)

Comment: Me parece que el "comportamiento esperado" es que funcionen todos de la misma forma. Es decir si escribo "[ tour ]" muestra "recorrido" (Que es el título de la página a la que apunta) y así con varios. Si alguno cree que faltan etiquetas, bienvenidas las ediciones :P

Comment: El primer nivel del magic-link es "centro de ayuda" es `help` y esa parte es la que se resuelve para el título. Dicho lo cual, podría mejorarse. Coincido con @Kacos en que esto debería ser una [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: Una solicitud de característica similar se publicó en Meta.SE en 2017: [“help center” magic link isn't click-friendly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289915/209901) y [Improve the link text of the magic link \[help/on-topic\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296745/209901)

Comment: A pedido de los demás usuarios, se agrega el tag "característica-nueva"

Comment: Camilo: me he tomado la libertad de reformular la pregunta para que sea petición, no bug, pues es el comportamiento esperado. Si estás en desacuerdo, no dudes en revertir mis cambios. ¡Gracias!