# Magic Link en Títulos de Ayuda y en la Descripción

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Si navegamos en el sistema de ayuda en general, éstos artículos tienen un [link mágico](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058/conoces-los-magic-links-para-los-comentarios-aprende-a-usarlos). Pero este link no se ve en el mismo artículo, ni se menciona. El usuario tiene que verlo y preguntar al respecto, para saber si existen *shortcuts* o algo para estas URLs, por lo cual el uso de los link mágicos no se promueve.

Entonces yo tengo estas propuestas:

1. Podemos agregar el link mágico en el título del artículo en la sección de ayuda. Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

[image: Ejemplo de link mágico en el titulo de la publicación]

2. Agregar en el artículo de ayuda, como parte de su contenido, que éste tiene un link mágico.

[image: Ejemplo de link mágico como parte del contenido del artículo de ayuda]

Comment: Me gusta esta propuesta, veamos que opina la comunidad. Ojalá sea algo que podamos implementar en [es.so] y que no sea un cambio que afecte a toda la red.

Comment: el cambio esta sujeto a la traducciones asique no es algo que afecte a la red completa.